# php pages includes not working if same are included

Tags: php, include

i have a page that needs to include functions.php and also show the content of another. This other page also have functions.php included and it gives error.

/index.php (.htaccess redirects here)

```
include_once '/themes/default/views/layouts/main.php';

function showContent() {
[...]
}
```

/themes/default/views/layouts/main.php

```
include_once('/includes/functions.php'); //why this include doesn't work for login.php

// html and php code

showContent(); //will include login.php
```

/views/site/login.php

```
include_once('/includes/functions.php');

//php and html code
```

So i get undefined variable notices and other errors... And i don't understand why if i remove the include from login.php will also give error... I mean the problem is to have 2 times the include_once.

How can i fix this?

Ty!

Edit: adding error files:

login.php

```
include('includes/functions.php');

sec_session_start();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $logged = 'in';
} else {
    $logged = 'out';
}
?>
```

$mysqli is created in db_connect.php that is included in functions.php

db_connect.php

```
include_once 'config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Comment: The point of include_once() is to only include the file once. You need to show the error that it's giving you.

Comment: Ok, if main page and other included page (from showcontent function, no matter what) have the same include_once it gives 2 errors: "Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\login.php on line 7" and "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\functions.php on line 151". line 7 from login is a call to a function: if (login_check($mysqli) == true) the other is a prepared statement if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SQL"))

Comment: You get the call to member function on non-object error, when you try to call a function in $this-> scope when the object hasn't been instantiated. It's hard to tell on the other errors without know what's in those files.

Comment: Ok, i'll add them. How can i make that instance? Is it neccesary to make that instance in every if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SQL"))??

Comment: This is weird, if i use include instead of include_once in login i get this error... "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sec_session_start() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\functions.php:6) in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\functions.php on line 26" line 6 is "function sec_session_start() {" and line 26 is "}"